# Task-Class not available in Mono 3.2.3

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm using Xamarin Studio (Alpha or Beta-Channel) with Mono 3.2.3 by default. When trying to compile my project (a PCL), I have compile errors.

Missing are the

```
System.Threading.Task
```

and the

```
System.Collections.Concurrent
```

Namespaces. 
With Mono 2.10.12 it compiles without problems, friends told me that 3.2.1 is also working fine. So my question: Is it a bug? And how can a go back easily to 3.2.1?